# How can I scroll in the Apple Watch simulator

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, xcode9, watchos

I want to test the complication but I can't scroll the complication in following screen (in simulator).

Other screens of the simulator can be scrolled by mouse.  I'm using Xcode 9.

[image: Setting Complication]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS.html

Comment: The link says: "Twist the crown clockwise - Drag up in the content window of the watch." But the doesn't help the test of complication

Comment: You can scroll the same way as in the iPhone Simulator. Use your mouse/trackpad.

Comment: I can't using Magic mouse with Xcode 9. Which Xcode you use?

Comment: @DávidPásztor do you agree?

Comment: Was just running into this, and it seems a picker *does* require you to position the mouse over the crown in the emulator -- it seems the scroll wheel / touchpad approach works for views that exceed the viewport only.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scroll you mouse at the crown area (image below) and then you can scroll the content in the simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll among complications using the mouse's scroll wheel or the touch pad. There's no need to position your cursor in a specific part of the simulator.